Negative percent deviance explained boosted regression tree
Thanks all for the help in advance.
I am building a series of boosted regression trees in R using the gbm.step function from the dismo package (V1.3.16). The response is species presence or absence, and the predictor variables are a suite of environmental variables such as sea surface temperature and bathymetry. The code used to generate the BRTs is pasted here:
library(dismo)

mod_file <- dismo::gbm.step(
      data = dat_train, 
      gbm.x = pred_vars, 
      gbm.y = 5,
      family = "bernoulli", 
      tree.complexity = 3,
      learning.rate = 0.05, 
      bag.fraction = 0.75, 
      silent = TRUE, 
      plot.main = TRUE

I would like to evaluate model performance across different combinations of spatial regions and years, so the test datasets used to evaluate model performance were generated by subsampling 20% of a given region-year combination. An example brt model object can be found here, and an example test dataset can be found here. The model object is termed mod_file in the code below and the test data is termed test_file. Because of the way I am subsampling the test datasets, some of them had a low n (100-400) relative to other spatiotemporal combinations (>1000). For the spatiotemporal combinations with low sample sizes, I am getting negative percent deviance explained values during model evaluation. I am calculating the percent deviance explained using the following code:
library(gbm)

#loop through each spatiotemporal combination

for(i in 1:length(unique(test_file$st_id))){ 

    #create empty dataset to store deviance explained values
    if(i == 1){
    temp_df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 9))
    cols_names <- c("dev_exp", "st_id")
    colnames(temp_df) <- cols_names  
    }
    
    #seperate for each spatiotemporal combination
    st_id_temp <- unique(test_file$st_id)[i]
    test_temp <- test_file %>% filter(st_id == st_id_temp)
    
    #calculate percent deviance explained
    preds <- predict.gbm(mod_file, test_temp,
                         n.trees = mod_file$gbm.call$best.trees,
                         type = "response")
    observed <- test_temp$PA
    
    ext.residual.deviance <- calc.deviance(obs = test_temp$PA, pred=preds, family="bernoulli", calc.mean=TRUE) 
    
    null.dev =  calc.deviance(test_temp$PA ,rep(mean(test_temp$PA),length(test_temp$PA)), family="bernoulli", calc.mean=T)
    
    dev=(null.dev - ext.residual.deviance)/null.dev 
      
    #store metric in performance metric dataframe
    temp_df$dev_exp[i] <- dev
temp_df$st_id[i] <- st_id_temp
  } 

Are there any methods or rules of thumb for proceeding with these negative values?

Welcome to Cross Validated! When you ask if there are any way to deal with these negative values, what do you want to do with them?

Dave gave a good answer below (+1). A second point is to ensure that we are validating our model with "reasonable" scenarios, i.e. if the subsampling creates impossible regions in terms of species abundance it might be that we testing our model against settings that the model should not work anyway.

@Dave By dealing with these values, I mean how could I go about plotting or reporting them. Is it common practice to plot negative deviance explained values? Or are they readjusted to 0? I was anticipating the model to perform poorly in this instance, but I was concerned about getting negative percent deviance explained scores and how to report them.

A negative value, viewed from the perspective in my answer, is perfectly interpretable. No, do not just round to zero. $//$ I cannot say if what you are doing makes for a reasonable comparison to a benchmark deviance, however.

dev=(null.dev - ext.residual.deviance)/null.dev is the critical line for understanding the situation. This can be written as:
$$
A=\dfrac{
B - C
}{
B
}
$$
Your situation is when $A<0$, so $\dfrac{
B - C
}{
B
}<0
$. A few steps of algebra shows that this is equivalent, assuming $B> 0$ (safe assumption in this case), to $C>B$.
$B$ is the null deviance, while $C$ is the model deviance. Thus, the model deviance is higher than the null deviance. That is, the model does a worse job of explaining, in some sense, the data than the null model does.
It may be disappointing, sure, that all of your hard work in fitting a model still can't beat a simple benchmark in the null model. However, this is still useful information. Before you put your model in production, you expose it for being rather poor.

(+1) In that regard, if we are getting very low generalisation performance, it is indicative that we likely overfitted our training data.
